# C++ Mutexes- Check if another thread is waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, mutex

Is it possible for a thread that already has a lock on a mutex to check whether another thread is already waiting, without releasing the mutex? For example, say a thread has 3 tasks to run on a block of data, but another thread may have a short task to run on the data as well. Ideally, I'd have the first thread check whether another thread is waiting between each of the three tasks and allow the other thread to execute its task before resuming the other two tasks. Does Boost have a type of mutex that supports this functionality (assuming the C++11 mutex or lock types don't support this), or can this be done with conditional variables?

Comment: Such functionality is not commonly provided because there are next to no use-cases for it and any such information is already stale by the tieme it is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check whether other threads are waiting on a mutex.

If you want to give other threads their chance to run, just release the mutex. No need to know if someone is waiting. Then re-acquire as necessary.

Conditional variables are events. Use them if you want to *wait* until something happens. To *check* whether something has happened you need a regular (mutex-protected or atomic) variable.

Comment: This solution does not work if releasing the resource is expensive, for example if it includes closing the database transaction, flushing I/O buffers and so on. In this case I have to release the resource, then release the lock, only to find out that nobody was waiting and get the lock back.

Answer (score 1):

you can not check if other threads are waiting on a mutex.

if you do need such functionality, you need to implement your own.
a mutex with use_count will suffice your need.

```
class my_mutex{
public:
   my_mutex() {count=0;}
   void lock() {count++; mtx.lock();}
   void unlock() {count--; mtx.unlock();}
   size_t get_waiting_threads() {return count>1?count-1:0;}
private:
   atomic_ulong count;
   mutex mtx;
};
```

if you need to finish task 1 and 2 before task 3 is executed, you should use conditional_variable instead of mutex.

Comment: Why do you use `return count>1?count-1:0;` instead of just `return count`?

Comment: 2William Rosenbloom
Because one thread is currently holding the mutex and doing some work, not waiting for the mutex.

Comment: 2naive_coach

It's a little bit safer to first unlock the mutex and then decrement the count, but even in this case readers should understand that this sample my_mutex should be used with caution because value of count can change between the point you check it and the point you take some action. So it can be used only in those cases where this fact does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If two threads are waiting on a lock, the thread that started waiting first is *not* guaranteed to be the thread that gets it first when it becomes available. So if you're a tight-looping thread who does something like

```
while(true):
  mutex.lock()
  print "got the lock; releasing it"
  mutex.unlock()
```

You might think you're being polite to all the other threads waiting for the lock, but you're not, the system might just give you the lock over and over again without letting any of the other threads jump in, no matter how long they've been waiting.

Condition variables are a reasonable way to solve this problem.